# is it true statement?

Tags: logic

prove or disprove

Let X be a set and suppose A and B are subsets of X

I try many examples but I find all of them give me that is true statement like

X={1,2,3,4,5} , A={1,2,3} , B={4,5}

X-A={4,5} , X-B={1,2,3}  , B-A={4,5}

please,anyone can confirm that for me is it true statement ?

Comment: @dxiv "suppose A and B are subsets of X"

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo Indeed, thanks. In that case, it's easiest to think in terms of complements in $X\,$: $\bar A \cap \bar {\bar B} = B \cap \bar A\,$.

Comment: What if you write $B-A$ as $B\cap A^c$? Now looking at left-hand side we get $$A^c\cap B^{cc}=A^c\cap B.$$

Comment: it is clear from your hint that is true statement , right ? thanks

Comment: Just keep in mind that $X-A=A^c$ since $A\subset X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(X-A)-(X-B)=A^c-B^c=A^c\cap(B^c)^c=B\cap A^c=B-A$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, to convince myself I'd consider there are four types of elements.

1) elements in both A and B.  They aren't in B-A as all A are excluded.  The aren't in (X-A)-(X-B) as all A are exclude.

2)elements in A but not B.  Again all A are excluded from both.

3)elements in B but not in A.  These are precisely the elements in $B-A $.  As they are not A there are in $X-A $ as they are in B, they are not in X-B and so they are not excluded from $(X-A)-(X-B) $.  So they are in.

4)elements in neither B nor A.  As they aren't in B, they aren't in B-A.  All the elements not in B are excluded from $(X-A)-(X-B) $ so they aren't in there either.

So the two sets have the same elements and exclude the same.